# Failed Public Test

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My code:

```
public class Film {
    private Darsteller hauptdarsteller;
    private String titel;
    private int erscheinungsjahr;
    private int fsk;
    private Genre genre;
    private Blyadflix portal;

    public Film(String _titel, int _erscheinungsjahr, int _fsk, Genre _genre) {
        this.titel = _titel;
        this.erscheinungsjahr = _erscheinungsjahr;
        this.fsk = _fsk;
        this.genre = _genre;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Film)) {
            return false;
        }
        Film f = (Film) o;
        return this.getErscheinungsjahr() == f.getErscheinungsjahr()
                && this.getHauptdarsteller() == f.getHauptdarsteller() && this.getTitel() == f.getTitel()
                && this.getFsk() == f.getFsk() && this.getGenre() == f.getGenre();
    }

    public Darsteller getHauptdarsteller() {
        return hauptdarsteller;
    }

    public void setHauptdarsteller(Darsteller hauptdarsteller) {
        this.hauptdarsteller = hauptdarsteller;
    }

    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    public void setTitel(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }

    public int getErscheinungsjahr() {
        return erscheinungsjahr;
    }

    public void setErscheinungsjahr(int erscheinungsjahr) {
        this.erscheinungsjahr = erscheinungsjahr;
    }

    public int getFsk() {
        return fsk;
    }

    public void setFsk(int fsk) {
        this.fsk = fsk;
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public Blyadflix getPortal() {
        return portal;
    }

    public void setPortal(Blyadflix portal) {
        this.portal = portal;
    }
}
```

PublicTests.java: Compile error

```
constructor Film in class Film cannot be applied to given types;f =
new Film("Ein Tag im Zoo", 2002, 18, Genre.DRAMA, d);             
required: String,int,int,Genre   found:
String,int,int,Genre,Darsteller   reason: actual and formal argument
lists differ in length
```

How Can I solve it?

Comment: And, again, you're not posting the relevant code, that is the one that gives you the error and its context. Please [edit] your question and post all the relevant information. Even better, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like you are missing a parameter in your Constructor...  or have an extra parameter whereever you are instantiating the Film object.

it would help to read-up on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call the constructor `Film(String, int, int, Genre, Darsteller)` but your class only has one constructor, `Film(String, int, int, Genre)`. You'll need to write a second constructor that also takes a `Darsteller` object:

```
public Film(String _titel, int _erscheinungsjahr, int _fsk, Genre _genre, Darsteller _hauptdarsteller) {
    this.titel = _titel;
    this.erscheinungsjahr = _erscheinungsjahr;
    this.fsk = _fsk;
    this.genre = _genre;
    this.hauptdarsteller = _hauptdarsteller;
}
```